# Does page impression get counted for unique visits?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

in Google adsense, if a user from any territory revisits page impression is getting updated but that eCPM is not getting updated its showing zero only, does it work only for unique visitors?

Thanks Sneha

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? It is not clear what you are trying to explain and what the question is.

Answer (score 2):

The "eCPM" is "Effective Cost per Mille" or the cost per 1,000 impressions. So if you had 2,000 visitors and earned $2, your eCPM would be $1.

Unique visitors are not counted, only raw page views. But if eCPM is showing as zero, it means either you are not earning anything (no one clicked on the advert) or simply there is not enough data to calculate it accurately.

Comment: oh, But i am getting page impressions count as some 50 or 60 but eCPM is showing zero for the day. How is it so? some time i get eCPm as 2$ or 3 like tat, some times i get eCPM as 0 even if we have page impression. why is it so?

Comment: What are your earnings when you have eCPM of 0? If they are very low then the CPM is close to 0 or not really possible to calculate.