# Does a returning visitor to a web page count as a page impression in Google Adsense?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

Suppose Mr.X visits a blog post on my website, views an advertisement by Google Adsense, gets what he came for and leaves the site. After some time, for some reason, he again visits the same blog post on my site and sees the same advertisement.

Will the return visit of Mr.X be counted as 2 impressions by Google Adsense or 1 impression? And is there any time span (or something) after which it will be counted as 2 impressions?

I searched Google, but did not manage to find a specific answer.

Found a QA at this link: [Does page impression get counted for unique visits?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/does-page-impression-get-counted-for-unique-visits) but neither did I understand the question nor do I think it addresses my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, That will be counted as 2 impression because "An impression is counted for each ad request that returns at least one ad to the site. It is the number of ad units (for content ads) or search queries (for search ads) that showed ads."

So there will be two Ad request for the same Ad but the Unique impression will be counted as 1.

Source: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6157410?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So then will I get paid for the 2 impressions or for 1 (unique) impression?

Comment: I'm not sure but may be you'll get paid for only unique impression.